# Why can't I print the value of x in this code?

Tags: python-3.6

```
from os import urandom
from math import log

def urandint(a,b):
    x=urandom(int(log(b-a+1)/log(256))+ 1)
    total = 0
    for (i,y) in enumerate(x):
        total +=y*(2**i)
    return total%(b-a+1)+a

print(urandint(5,8))
print(x)
```

When I try to print the value of x I get this error:./urandom_function.py

```
7
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./urandom_function.py", line 14, in <module>
    print(x)
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

How do I correct this and print the value of x?

Comment: `x` was a local variable inside `urandint()`.  It *ceases to exist* when the function returns.  There is no possible way to print it at the point where you're trying to print it - you would either have to return it from the function, or store it in a global variable or other location that will survive the end of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Not very proficient in my programming but from what I can tell because 'x' is a local variable and therefore can't be accessed from outside. Try putting 'print(x) inside your function. i.e.,

from os import urandom

from math import log

def urandint(a,b):

```
x = urandom(int(log(b-a+1)/log(256))+ 1)
print(x)
total = 0
for (i,y) in enumerate(x):
    total +=y*(2**i)
return total%(b-a+1)+a
```

print(urandint(5,8))

Answer :
b'\xb6'
7